# jQuery check Right position after animation ends

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following jQuery code

```
$('.sidebar-address').animate({
    'right' : "+=500px"
});

var sideBarPos = $('.sidebar-address').css('right');
console.log(sideBarPos);
```

I'd like to check the position after the animation has ended but it returns -500px each time instead it should be giving me the value 0.

Comment: set a timeout to the console.log to see if it start before or after the animation.

Comment: What are the value of right for inline (added by animate) and the external css value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check it after the animation is finished, so you need to put it in the animate's callback like:

```
$('.sidebar-address').animate({
    'right' : "+=500px"
},function(){
    var sideBarPos = $(this).css('right');
    console.log(sideBarPos);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/se7h2/)**

Otherwise your code is running before the animation is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities. Create a setTimeout function for your console.log and variable or put it in the callback of the animation.

Example putting the code in the callback (best solution).

```
$('.sidebar-address').animate({
    'right' : "+=500px"
},function(){
    var sideBarPos = $('.sidebar-address').css('right');
    console.log(sideBarPos);
});
```

Example using setTimeout, just to test the result of your animation:

```
$('.sidebar-address').animate({
    'right' : "+=500px"
});

setTimeout(function() {
    var sideBarPos = $('.sidebar-address').css('right');
    console.log(sideBarPos);
}, 1000); // if animation is 900, put 1000.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of it showing before the animation has finished you could add the code as a callback.

```
$('.sidebar-address').animate({
    'right' : "+=500px"
}, ANIMATION-TIME, function() {
    console.log($(this).css('right'));
);
```